# RadioButtonList verifying index

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Radiobuttonlist and I want after the Item with value 1 is selected to do something. When I used **RadioButtonListType.SelectedValue** is returning **""** and when I use **RadioButtonListType.SelectedIndex** is returning **-1**.
Where I am doing wrong ?

this is my code

**aspx**

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonListType" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonListType_SelectedIndexChanged" ValidationGroup="emergency" AutoPostBack="True">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Normal</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Emergency</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**.cs**

```
protected void RadioButtonListType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButtonListSF.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        MPEEmergency.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a mismatch with your ID
`ID="RadioButtonListType"` and `RadioButtonListSF.SelectedIndex`

Comment: Oh , I did not see that . Thank you